# Round off Value for on 1.5 to 1 in php?

Tags: php

I am using old PHP version 5.2.8 (XAMPP 1.7.0). And I want to round off 1.5 to 1. Due to PHP version I cannot use

```
echo round(1.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 1
```

I need outputs like

> 1.3 => 1
>   1.5 => 1
>   1.61 => 2
>   1.7 => 2

Comment: Floor won't work 1.61 will not be 2 then

Comment: Yes bro it step down nearest value

Comment: And the obvious question: Why not upgrade PHP to a supported, faster and way more secure version?

Comment: some technical issue. Want to change encoders and coding styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract 0.1 from the number and round it normally.

```
$arr =[ 1.3 ,1.5,1.61, 1.7];
Foreach($arr as $v){
   Echo $v . " => " .round($v-0.1) . "\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/0XRPV

Edit or 0.01 if you want 1.51 => 2.
Above code makes 1.51 => 1

Comment: Yes bro, I think we can change it by if(abs($arr[1]-round($arr[1])) ==0.5){ //code.. } https://3v4l.org/C3v4c

Comment: The output is the same, not sure what you gain on it

Answer (score 0):

In below code you can dynamically assign value to variable $a and can get answer in round

```
<?php
        $a = 1.3;       //change with your variable
        $b = explode('.', $a);       
        $length = strlen($b[1]);   
        $i=1;
        $c=5;
        while ($i< $length) {          //create value of after point
            $c.=0;
            $i++;
        }
        if($c<$b[1]){              //check value less then or greater then
            $result=$b[0]+1;
        }else{
            $result=$b[0];
        }
        echo $result;              //your result value after round
    ?>
```

Try this this will help you